# How can we add alternate node data?

Tags: c++, c, singly-linked-list

How can we add data from alternating nodes from given singly linked list?

For example lets say we have 6 nodes with following integers as data: 1 2 3 4 5 6.
So we are supposed to add all the alternate nodes as 1+3+5=9 similarly 2+4+6=12 so output should be 13 and 11.

My approach was bad because it was crashing and here it is:

```
while(temp->next!=NULL)
{ 
  if(temp->next->next!=NULL)
  {
    sum=temp->data + temp->next->next->data;
  }
  else
  {
    sum=sum+temp->data;
  }
  return sum;
} //similarly i did for adding other alternate node data
```

Please can anyone suggestion me good and best approach?

Comment: Why 1, 3, 4 and 5 for the first one, and why 2, 4 and 5 for the second?

Comment: @immibis sorry i have edit now nodes with data are  1 2 3 4 5 6 i am supposed to add adjacent data i.e 1+3(skip 2)+5(skip 4)=9 similarly 2+4+6=12

Comment: What you mean is "alternate", not "adjacent". If your instructor said "adjacent", then you may be misunderstanding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to return two `int`s, create a `struct` for the output:

```
struct sum_output
{
    int first;
    int second;
};
```

Make that the return type of the function.

```
struct sum_output sum(node* list);
```

Compute the `first` and the `second` members of the `struct` by iterating over the nodes of the list and return it.

```
struct sum_output sum(node* list)
{
    struct sum_output ret = {0, 0};
    for ( ; list != NULL; list = list->next )
    {
       ret.first += list->data;
       if ( list->next != NULL )
       {
          ret.second += list->next->data;
          list = list->next;
       }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just should do aggregate alternately by preparing the variable of total for the two.
The following example

```
int ff = 0, sum[2] = {0};

while(temp){
    sum[ff] += temp->data;
    temp = temp->next;
    ff = !ff;//0 -> 1, 1-> 0
}
printf("%d, %d\n", sum[0], sum[1]);
//Using a pointer if there is a need to return a value to the caller as a function
//*out1 = sum[0];*out2 = sum[1];
```

---

```
void sum(node_type *temp, int *out1, int *out2){
    int ff = 1, sum[2] = {0};

    for(;temp; temp = temp->next)
        sum[ff = !ff] += temp->data;

    out1 && (*out1 = sum[0]);//call E.g sum(head, &sum1, &sum2);//sum(head, &sum1, NULL);sum(head, NULL, &sum2);
    out2 && (*out2 = sum[1]);
}
```

Comment: Can you amend your answer with some explanation of your code?